# JQuery .load() character encoding problem in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery, character-encoding

IE (i'm using 8) will not show any swedish characters in a document loaded through jquery .load(). The file is part of the former page the client wants untouched, so I can't go in and change the encoding. 
This is the code I used to embed a fragment from an HTM doc into the current one (The HTM document is in Windows-1252 and nothing else would work to fix it on Firefox):

```
$.ajaxSetup({contentType: 'text/html;charset=windows-1252'});

$.ajaxSetup({
        'beforeSend' : function(xhr) {
             xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=windows-1252');
        },
});

$("#best").load("http://alltomven.se/09-0005-05.htm #table2");
```

I even have a fix I used for Firefox in there, but this doesn't work for IE. None of the diacritical characters show. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe we should try to use UTF-8 charset?

Comment: Tried changing that on the HTM doc. I think the problem is that something happens when the doc is run through jQuery, so changing both documents to utf-8 didn't work for me.

Comment: your page http://alltomven.se/09-0005-05.htm returns "Content-Type: text/html" in header. Therefore, xhr believes that response is utf-8 charset. Solutions 2 way: first, you convert page in utf-8, second, you return "Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252" in header.